# UITableViewCell and UITableView Repeat selection over other Cells?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am working in **UITableView** and trying to let the user to select cells using this code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(cell != nil)
    {
        if(cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        }
        else
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }
    }
}
```

but the problem is when the cell count over one page if you select cell number 1 the row number 1 in each page will be selected too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
static NSString * cellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier"
```

in this place use

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%i",indexPath.row];
```

Comment: Why this second answer? You should edited your first answer instead.

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain why this fixed the problem?

Comment: You saved my day. thank you. this solved the problem!

Answer (score 5):

Nice answer, you really helped put me on the right track.

My 2 cents to help somebody else:

I'm using a grouped table so I changed it up a bit to make it:

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%i-%i", indexPath.section, indexPath.row];
```

Hope this helps somebody else.

Answer (score 2):

use this pass the global variable one class to other class or one view controller to a other view controller.

```
globalString=[Arrayname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Write this code in tableviewdidselect delegate method.